# Django alphanumeric CharField

Tags: django, django-models

How can I create a CharField on a Django model that can only have numbers and letters?

```
models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a Django form field contain only alphanumeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165147/how-can-i-make-a-django-form-field-contain-only-alphanumeric-characters)

Answer (score 6):

another option is to use `validators` option for the CharField ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#validators))

Answer (score 6):

Control at Model-level may include some unwanted behavior, these are equivalent to schema constraints and will apply when manipulating the db (ie: backups), if you are absolutely sure you need control at Model level instead of Form then you should define a new [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) or use an existing one.

The basic way of testing a string for alphanumeric is

```
'string'.isalpha()
```

You could put that evaluation in the save method of the model, but if you want to have more control or raise a ValidationError automatically you can define a validator for the model. This way let's you do unit testing without involving the form. However, make sure your implementation doesn't affect your performance.

#### Example:

"automated tasks fetching hex32 tokens from a remote server", so you check those tokens at run time with a validator like:

```
RegexValidator(r'^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$',
               message='Key must be Hex len 32',
               code='Invalid Key')
```

And if it doesn't match you raise a ValidationError with the details automatically.

In your case, you could do:

*models.py*:

```
from validators import isalphavalidator

class SomeModel(Model):
    some_alpha_field = models.CharField(_('name'), validators=[isalphavalidator], max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
```

*validators.py*

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


'''
This regex assumes that you have a clean string,
you should clean the string for spaces and other characters
'''

isalphavalidator = RegexValidator(r'^[\w]*$',
                             message='name must be alphanumeric',
                             code='Invalid name')
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a CharField use a [RegexField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#regexfield) instead with `regex="[A-z0-9]+"`

You can make the field real easy using the same logic:

```
class AlphaNumericField(CharField):
    def clean(self, value, model_instance):
        value = super(AlphaNumericField, self).clean(value, model_instance)
        if not re.match(r'[A-z0-9]+', value):
            raise ValidationError('AlphaNumeric characters only.')
        return value
```

Comment: RegexField is in the Forms, i need it in the model.

Comment: I added an example of making a custom field.

Comment: Django Complains, that the clean method only accepts 2 arguments, but given 3, using the approach above.

Comment: Really? I get "takes exactly 2 arguments, 1 given" with the code (too _few_ passed in, not too _many_)

Comment: following the good Django practices: Where should i put this code? in forms.py?

Comment: @NicolasRojo I usually put stuff like this at the site-wide level (next to the top-most urls.py) in a file called fields.py. So then you do `from mysite.fields import AlphaNumericField` where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **RegexValidator**, give validation in forms attributes only like...

```
        *class StaffDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
             first_name = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control' , 'autocomplete': 'off','pattern':'[A-Za-z ]+', 'title':'Enter Characters Only '}))*
```

and so on...

If you are using **RegexValidator** you will have to handle the error in views.
It worked for me try this simple method...
This will allow users to enter only Alphabets and Spaces only