# How can I make a Django form field contain only alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, django

I have this model

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

I want that the user should not be able to use any other characters than alphanumerics in both fields.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You would use a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/) to limit what the field accepts. A [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) would do the trick here:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
```

Note that there already is a [`validate_email` validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#validate-email) that'll validate email addresses for you; the `alphanumeric` validator above will not allow for valid email addresses.

Comment: The user might struggle to add a valid email address with the `alphanumeric` validator ;)

Comment: @Alasdair . i just want to get the idea. i will use this  `[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{6,}`. is that ok

Comment: i tried and it says name alphnumeric is not defined. i have declared in outside Model

Comment: @user1958218: There is a dedicated email validator. Sorry, I made a typo in the name there, please re-copy-and-paste.

Comment: Is there some way to achieve this in direct response to the keys the user submits? Instead of waiting for after form submission?

Comment: @JamesWierzba: see [django forms client side validation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16327065)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of RegexValidator, give validation in forms attributes only like...

```
        class StaffDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
             first_name = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control' , 'autocomplete': 'off','pattern':'[A-Za-z ]+', 'title':'Enter Characters Only '}))
```

and so on...

Else you will have to handle the error in views.
It worked for me try this simple method...
This will allow users to enter only Alphabets and Spaces only

Comment: Remembar that's only frontend validation!! You should also add RegexValidator validation to validate value of that field in backend!

Answer (score 2):

That is little bit wider than you want, but you also can use `SlugField`:

> A Slug is basically a short label for something, containing only
> letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in
> URLs. For example, in a typical blog entry URL:
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-the-slug-field-inside-django-model/

```
field_name = models.SlugField(max_length=200, **options)
```

Answer (score 0):

**email validation using django form**
*with danish special characters also*

```
import re

email_regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-øØæÆåÅ]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-øØæÆåÅ]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'

if email and not re.search(email_regex, email):
    raise forms.ValidationError({"email": "Enter a valid email"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of builtin string isalnum function to check whether input is alphanumeric or not.

```
def alphanumeric(value):
    if not str(value).isalnum():
        raise ValueError("Name can have number or character no special characters")


name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
```

Comment: Probably adding description to explain, how is it working or what it does, would be very helpful.

Comment: Note that this _isn't_ actually a very good validation for people's names. For example: `"Johnny Appleseed".isalnum()` evaluates to False becuse of the space.